# Deriving the Bayes Filter Correction Equation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, naive-bayes, bayes, filter

The correction rule for Bayes filters is: $$p\left(x_{k}|D_{k}\right)=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}|x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(x_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}
 $$

For:

- State at time $k$ is $x_{k}$
- Observation at time $k$ is $y_{k}$,
- Past Observations at time $k$ and earlier are $D_{k}=(y_{k},y_{k-1},...)$

I am trying to derive it. In all derivations/explinations of Bayes filters i have found,
it just says for this step *"Simply apply Bayes Rule."*.

To my knowledge, bayes rule is: $p\left(x_{k}|y_{k}\right)=p\left(y_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}\cap y_{k}\right)=p\left(x_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}\cap y_{k}\right)
 $

#### So I apply it on LHS:

$$p\left(x_{k}|D_{k}\right)=\dfrac{p\left(x_{k}\cap D_{k}\right)}{p\left(D_{k}\right)}$$

#### Then I take a look at the right hand side:

$$RHS=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}|x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(x_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}$$

$RHS=\dfrac{\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}\cap x_{k}\right)}{p\left(x_{k}\right)}\cdot\dfrac{p\left(x_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(D_{k-1}\right)}}{\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(D_{k-1}\right)}}$
  Expand Conditionals

$RHS=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}\cap x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(x_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(y_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)}$
  Cancel terms

$RHS=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}\cap x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(x_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(D_{k}\right)}$
 substitute definition of
$p\left(D_{k}\right)=p\left(y_{k}\cap D_{k-1}\right)$

But then I get stuck. I don't see any where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula$$p\left(x_{k}|D_{k}\right)=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}|x_{k}\right)\cdot p\left(x_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}$$ is Bayes' rule (or Bayes' Theorem) *conditional on $D_{k-1}$*. Not what you wrote as your "knowledge of bayes rule", i.e., $p\left(x_{k}|y_{k}\right)=p\left(y_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}\cap y_{k}\right)=p\left(x_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}\cap y_{k}\right)$ which does not hold, the lhs is the joint distribution of $x_k$ and $y_k$. The proper way to define the conditional pdf $p\left(x_{k}|y_{k}\right)$ is
$$p\left(x_{k}|y_{k}\right) = \dfrac{p\left(x_{k},y_{k}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}\right)}$$ 
And the generic *Bayes rule* is the inversion of the above
$$p\left(x_{k}|y_{k}\right) = \dfrac{p\left(y_k|x_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}\right)}$$
(Avoid using the symbol '$\cap$' in joint densities as it only applies for *discrete* variables.)

The key is in the above filter formula is that it relies on the assumption that $y_k$ is independent from $D_{k-1}$ given $x_k$. 
\begin{align*}
p(x_k|D_k) &= \frac{p(x_k,D_k)}{p(D_k)}\\
&=\frac{p(x_k,y_k,D_{k-1})}{p(D_k)}\\
&=\frac{p(y_k|x_k,D_{k-1})p(x_k,D_{k-1})}{p(D_k)}\qquad\text{conditional+marginal}\\
&=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k,D_{k-1})}{p(D_k)}\ \qquad\text{independence assumption}\\
&=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|D_{k-1})p(D_{k-1})}{p(y_k,D_{k-1})}\\
&=\frac{p(y_k|x_k)p(x_k|D_{k-1})p(D_{k-1})}{p(y_k|D_{k-1})p(D_{k-1})}\\
&=\dfrac{p\left(y_{k}|x_{k}\right)p\left(x_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}{p\left(y_{k}|D_{k-1}\right)}
\end{align*}
which gives the result. Once again, the independence assumption is crucial in this representation. Otherwise, $p(y_k|x_k)$ would have to be replaced with $p(y_k|x_k,D_{k-1})$.

Comment: I was thinking of $y_x$, and $x_k$ as being discrete. But now I realise they are not. Not at all.

Comment: Ok, now that I have found time to check thought it, it clears things up.
I think it would be abit clearer if you finished the proof with the final line being the result being proved.
It would also have helped me it you included a definition that $p(a|b)=p(a,b)/p(b)$
But it is a pretty solid answer alround, thanks.